# How to pull without losing local changes in sourcetree/git

Tags: git

I am having one project, where I and my partner is working simultaneously. The scenario is like,

I work on X feature in the same Unity3D scene.
He works on Y thing in the same Unity3D scene.

I push changes to cloud via sourcetree, later he pulls that but he loses track of his local work.

How can we avoid this situation?

Comment: when he pulls he should resolve the `merge conflicts` and accept both of your changes

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps whenever you have to take pull:-

- git stash
- git pull
- git stash pop

Always pull the changes before start working, that will reduce conflict problems

Answer (score 0):

When working on the same scene it would be better to work on object as prefabs and apply only the prefab that you are working on without pushing the scene but still.. you need to push the scene in the first time you create it.. bottom line : try to sync between all devs to split tasks so you don't have that kind of conflicts.